# torch7 neural network training error

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

I'm trying to implement a neural network example in torch7. my data is stored in a text file in this form [19 cols x 10000 rows] :

```
11 38 20 44 11 38 21 44 29 42 30 44 34 38  6 34 45 42 1
11 38 20 44 11 38 27 44 31 42 18 44 34 38  6 34 45 42 2
6  42 20 44 11 38 21 44 29 42 30 44 34 38  6 34 45 42 3
...
34 40 20 44 11 38 21 44 29 38 30 38 34 45 38  0  0  0 100
...
```

With labels in last column [100 labels].

With this code :

```
require 'nn'
-- ======================================= --
--           Start loading data   
-- ======================================= --
print '[INFO] Loading data..'
dataset = {}
function dataset:size() return 10000 end 
local lin = 1

train_file = 'train_10000.t7'
local file = io.open(train_file)
if file then
    for line in file:lines() do
            local input = torch.Tensor(18);
            local output = torch.Tensor(1);

        local X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, X16, X17, X18, Y = unpack(line:split(" "))                

        input  = {X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, X16, X17, X18}
        output = Y

        dataset[lin] = {input, output}        
        lin = lin +1        
    end
end
-- ======================================= --
--                 Create NN   
-- ======================================= --
print '[INFO] Creating NN..'
mlp = nn.Sequential();  -- make a multi-layer perceptron
inputs = 18; outputs = 1; HUs = 25; -- parameters
mlp:add(nn.Linear(inputs, HUs))
mlp:add(nn.Tanh())
mlp:add(nn.Linear(HUs, outputs))
-- ======================================= --
--           MSE and Training  
-- ======================================= --
print '[INFO] MSE and train NN..'
criterion = nn.MSECriterion()  
trainer = nn.StochasticGradient(mlp, criterion)
trainer.learningRate = 0.01
trainer:train(dataset)
```

I got this error message:

```
# StochasticGradient: training  
/home/yosaikan/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Linear.lua:34: attempt to call method 'dim' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    /home/yosaikan/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Linear.lua:34: in function 'updateOutput'
    ...e/yosaikan/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:25: in function 'forward'
    ...an/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/StochasticGradient.lua:35: in function 'train'
    iparseSchemeConversion.lua:45: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'f'
    [string "local f = function() return dofile 'iparseSch..."]:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/yosaikan/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/main.lua:174: in function </home/yosaikan/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/main.lua:140>
    /home/yosaikan/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/poller.lua:75: in function 'poll'
    .../yosaikan/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/impl/loop.lua:307: in function 'poll'
    .../yosaikan/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/impl/loop.lua:325: in function 'sleep_ex'
    .../yosaikan/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/impl/loop.lua:370: in function 'start'
    /home/yosaikan/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/main.lua:341: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    (command line):1: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00405980
```

Can you please help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I got this error message [...] Can you please help me?

Within your dataset `input` and `output` should be `Tensor`-s (here `input` is a plain Lua table which is why you obtain this error, i.e there is no `dim` method).

To simplify data loading I recommend you to use a [csv parser](http://luarocks.org/search?q=csv), e.g you can use [csv2tensor](https://github.com/willkurt/csv2tensor) to load your data into a `Tensor`.

First make sure to add a header (as first line) to your file like:

```
x001,x002,x003,x004,x005,x006,x007,x008,x009,x010,x011,x012,x013,x014,x015,x016,x017,x018,label
```

Then load your data as follow:

```
local csv2tensor = require 'csv2tensor'

local inputs = csv2tensor.load("data.csv", {exclude={"label"}})
local labels = csv2tensor.load("data.csv", {include={"label"}})

local dataset = {}

for i=1,inputs:size(1) do
  dataset[i] = {inputs[i], torch.Tensor{labels[i]}}
end

dataset.size = function(self)
  return inputs:size(1)
end
```

And use this dataset for training:

```
-- ...
trainer:train(dataset)
```

Comment: The answer you gave was the right one; 'Merci BIEN' (since it is not allowed in English for comments!). I have a couple of questions yet please : Should I normalize data set ? How to recuperate optimal weights values ?

Comment: You can get the weights with `mlp:getParameters()` (see this [documentation](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/module.md#flatparameters-flatgradparameters-getparameters)) or per-module, e.g `mlp:get(1).weight` and `mlp:get(1).bias`. Regarding normalization/rescaling: you might experiment.

Comment: @deltheil . This method reads the entire data.csv twice. Is there a way to read it once, then separate it into inputs and labels?

Comment: Here is a naive example (data is first loaded into tables, and then converted into tensors) that works with [this](https://github.com/geoffleyland/lua-csv) csv parser: [convert.lua](https://gist.github.com/deltheil/8a7e0d384a5bc0ca97a8).

Comment: great topic guys! I actually just had the same question. I set up the code pretty much identically as you suggested but im getting the error "attempt to index upvalue 'inputs' (a number value) stack traceback:
 /Users/robertgrzesik/Lua/async-master/tests/dp-test.lua:29: in function 'size'
 ...ik/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/StochasticGradient.lua:19: in function 'train'" which refers to "dataset.size = function(self)
  return inputs:size(1)
end". Any ideas?

Comment: For some reason `inputs` is not a tensor in your code but a number hence this error. You should double check why (perhaps you have replaced the variable in the meanwhile).

Comment: Awesome. I was able to solve it by pre setting the variable (maybe some weird memory things happening?). However, I ran into another issue, do you think you could take a look please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458330/size-mismatch-in-function-addmv-in-torch7